# Using delegate gives EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x2774….)

Tags: objective-c, delegates, exc-bad-access

I am totally new to iOS programming and I am trying to make a word game in which an alphabet tile is dragged and dropped to a target. I have adopted the code from www.raywenderlich.com/33806/how-to-make-a-letterword-game-with-uikit-part-2 .The problem is when I use the GameLogic class as a delegate to to match whether the alphabet dragged matches the target or not, it gives me EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x277… …). In GameLogic.m, even though the _targets and _tiles arrays are initialized within the dealRandomScrabble method, the error occurs when the protocol: (void)tileView:(TileView *)tileView didDragToPoint:(CGPoint)pt is called. In this method, tv and _targets surprisingly refer to null! Could anyone please look into my code and tell me what I have missed? The link to the code in my GoogleDrive is :

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzWvv9PVuvDKLWtJcldRbGVRNUk/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The code runs fine in the tutorial below, but when I use it, it doesn't. Help really needed on this!

www.raywenderlich.com/33806/how-to-make-a-letterword-game-with-uikit-part-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this method

-(void)dealRandomScrabble

// Initialize target list

instead of this line

```
 _targets = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:scrab2Len];
```

use below line.

```
_targets =[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:scrab2Len];
```

by doing so, _targets doesnt point to null in -(void)tileView:(TileView *)tileView didDragToPoint:(CGPoint)pt method(protocol method)

Comment: ps: i'm using ARC. high time u did it too

Comment: I tried this way too. The  problem is that letter in _targets should hold an alphabet as a string, but does not. Also, targetView should hold all the letters in the target, but does not. :(

Comment: using arc should hav been a decision made before u begin your project. Just a caution: u may face unseen challenges if you convert code to arc midway. u should read more about arc and mrc

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
_targets = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:scrab2Len];
```

with

```
_targets = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:scrab2Len] retain];
```

And make sure that u release this object once you are done

Comment: Wow Shanti, thanks for the prompt reply. Now _targets holds the alphabets, but the targetView holds no letter and gives bad memory access again in the if statement that follows:
// Check if target was found
    if (targetView != nil) {
        
        if ([targetView.letter isEqualToString:tileView.letter]){
            
            NSLog(@"Success! You should place the tile here!");
            
            NSLog(@"Check if the player has completed the phrase");
        } else{
            NSLog(@"Failure. Let the player know this tile doesn't match.");
        }
    }

Comment: Could you kindly run the project I shared to get a better understanding of my problem. I truly appreciate your help!